# Permission denied on key when encrypting secrets.yml file with helm and gcp_kms

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm, encryption-symmetric, kubernetes-secrets

I have a keyring and key in Google Cloud KMS. I want to use the key to encrypt a secrets.yml file using helm secrets enc

I am the GCP project owner, and I have also given myself the specific encrypt/decrypt IAM role, which I don't think is needed, given I am the owner, but worth a try a thought.

I'm getting the following permission denied error when trying to run helm secrets enc secrets.yml:

> Could not generate data key: [failed to encrypt new data key with
> master key
> "projects/myproject-266813/locations/global/keyRings/myKeyRing/cryptoKeys/myKey":
> Failed to call GCP KMS encryption service: googleapi: Error 403:
> Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt' denied on
> resource
> 'projects/myproject-266813/locations/global/keyRings/myKeyRing/cryptoKeys/myKey'
> (or it may not exist)., forbidden]

My .sops.yml file:

```
creation_rules:
- gcp_kms: projects/mirkwood-266813/locations/global/keyRings/lotr/cryptoKeys/cdlkey
```

I am authenticated with the correct gcp account, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this turned out to be really simple:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

or

use a service account

```
gcloud auth login
```

on it's own did not work